# How do I web-scrape this website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website to print out events with their time and date

```
with open('events.html', 'r',  encoding='utf-8') as html_file:
content = html_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
free_slot = soup.find_all('tr', class_='views-field views-field-title')
for slot in free_slot:
    event_name = slot.a.text
    event_time = slot.time.text

    print(event_name)
    print(event_time)
```

events.html contains this

Bystander Intervention: Live Workshop        
                                                                      Glasnevin Campus        
                                                                      Solas Room, The U         
                                                                      Student Support & Development        
                                                                      February 15, 13:00
 - February 15, 13:50

The html is from this website : https://www.dcu.ie/students/events
When I try run the code it just returns '[]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What happens?

ResultSet is empty cause there is no `<tr>` with these classes defined in your `find_all()`.

#### How to fix?

Remove the classes from your `find_all()` and iterate over:

```
free_slot = soup.find_all('tr')
for slot in free_slot:
    print(slot)
    event_name = slot.a.text
    event_time = slot.time.text

    print(event_name)
    print(event_time)
```

#### How to scrape the table?

You can do it using `BeautifulSoup` but I think to get the contents of table it is much more simple to use `pandas` built-in `read_html`, that will do the job for you:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://www.dcu.ie/students/events')[0]
```

#### Output

| Unnamed: 0 | Campus | Venue | Department | Event date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bystander Intervention: Live Workshop | Glasnevin Campus | Solas Room, The U | Student Support & Development | February 15, 13:00 - February 15, 13:50 |
| Emotional Intelligence: Ways to Ease Stress and Anxiety - Session 2 | Online | Online via Zoom | Student Support & Development | February 15, 13:00 - February 15, 14:00 |
| Critical writing | Online | Online via Zoom | Student Learning | February 15, 13:00 - February 15, 14:00 |
| Skills Session: Ace your Interview Skills | Online | Online | Careers Service | February 15, 13:00 - February 15, 13:50 |
| Bystander Intervention: Live Workshop | St Patrick's Campus | B108, Auditorium | Student Support & Development | February 15, 17:00 - February 15, 17:50 |
| Bystander Intervention: Live Workshop | Glasnevin Campus | Cuilin Room, The U | Student Support & Development | February 15, 18:00 - February 15, 18:50 |
| How to Survive a Technical Interview with Microsoft | Online | Online | Careers Service | February 16, 10:00 - February 16, 11:00 |
| Going Global Job Seach Training Session | Online | Virtual | Careers Service | February 16, 10:00 - February 16, 11:00 |
| Informative session and a Q&A on the Vodafone Ireland Summer Internship Programme 2022. | Online | Online | Careers Service | February 16, 12:00 - February 16, 13:00 |